# Error with package import in java

Tags: java, scope, package

I have package LibUtil with  file Item.java in directory LibUtil. In this file i have `public class Item`

```
package LibUtil;
public class Item
{
 static protected int id=0;
 protected int type;
 protected String name;
 protected String category;

public Item(int type,String name,String category)
 {
  id++;
  this.type = type;
  this.name = name;
  this.category = category;
 }

 public int GetId()
 {
  return id;
 }

 public int GetType(){
   return type;
  } 


 public void SetType(int type){
   this.type = type;
  }

 public String GetName(){
   return name;
  }

 public void SetName(String name){
   this.name = name;
  }

 public void SetCategory(){
   this.category = category;
  }
public String getCategory(){
   return category;
  }
}
```

I import this class from LibUtil.

```
import LibUtil.Item;
public class Library{
 public static void main(String[] args){
   Item test = new Item(1,"XYZ","Alpha");


    }

}
```

When i'm traing compile this project compiler produces output like this:

```
Library.java:1: LibUtil.Item is not public in LibUtil; cannot be accessed from outside package
import LibUtil.Item;
              ^
Library.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Item
location: class Library
   Item test = new Item(1,"XYZ","Alpha");
   ^
Library.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Item
location: class Library
   Item test = new Item(1,"XYZ","Alpha");
                   ^
3 errors
```

How solve this problem?

Upd: i try to rebuild project with command:

```
javac LibUtil/Item.java
javac Library.java
```

Comment: try to clean ur project and run ?

Comment: Can you show us the folder structure?

Comment: base_dir\LibUtil\Item.java  base_dir\Library.java

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: "Item is not public in LibUtil". I know you recompiled your code already, so you might want to check if there are any outdated Item.class files lingering on your classpath.

Comment: I recommend using Maven or Gradle so that you can easily clean your projects.

Comment: Don't you change `.class` files location? Do you have `Library.class` in `base_dir\` and `Item.class` in `base_dir\LibUtil`? Also do you run with command `java Library` inside `base_dir`?

Answer (score 0):

In my source files i find duplicate of Item.java. And in this duplicate class Item hasn't public modifier. Thank's for all author of answers in this topic